# Wordpress custom post types with child pages

Tags: php, wordpress, url, seo, structure

I am having difficulty trying to find a solution for my problematic.

We have a custom post type in wordpress named "stores" each store has a unique name example "LA store, NY Store" and each store will have child pages like location, opening hours etc.

But unfortunately its a hard work to create all child pages for each store. instead we would like to use some templates for the child pages.

We would like to have our url structure like:

> sample.com/store/lastore/opening-hours

Comment: Can you be more specific ? You want an alternative to the child page system ?

Comment: Hi amarinediary first of all thank you for your edit :)

Basically we dont want to create every single child pages in wordpress for each store, instead we want to create the stores and when user tries to access "sample.com/store/lastore/opening-hours" it should not go to 404 but instead include a template part

Comment: template part are exactly what they are, parts. they're not templates. You can't use one as a page. However, thinking about it you could [automatically generate a child page after the save_post action is fired upon publish a parent page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/85832/190376). And then you could set a page template for that page, and generate whatever data should be on it from the parent slug. (eg: fetching custom meta boxes values and so on) ...

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can modify the rewrite parameter when you register your post type. Below is an example:

```
$args = array(
           'labels'              => $labels,
           'hierarchical'        => true, // just to get parent child relationships with your custom post [but you already knew this part]
           'description'         => 'Your custom post type description here',
           'has_archive'         => false,
           'rewrite'             => array('slug' => '/'), // we rewrite the slug to the root url so that it has no post type prefix
           'with_front'          => false, // This is optional but just in case your posts are set to /blog/post-name this will make it /post-name for your custom post type 
           'capability_type'     => 'post',
           'supports'            => array(
                                          'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes'
                                    )
        );

register_post_type( 'post_type', $args );
```

Make sure you update the permalink structure after changes, so WordPress can rewrite the rules.